# Multiple Vagrant VMs via PuPHPet with different configs

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile, puphpet

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental. How do I use PuPHPet to define two machines in one vagrantfile, both Ubuntu 14.04, but one with mysql installed and one with elasticsearch? I see how to define multiple machines, but the config of each seems to be identical???

Comment: The config is probably the same but if you look the `puphpet/config.yaml` for each machine it will be different

Comment: @FrédéricHenri thank you, but I am referring to multiple machines created from within a single (PuPHPet-generated) Vagrantfile. PuPHPet allows you to create multiple machines in one file, but it appears that other than the most basic of information (hostname and IP essentially), they are clones of one another. This is quite different to the use cases described at: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/

Comment: puphpet multi-machine is based on vagrant multi machine (see https://blog.puphpet.com/blog/2016/03/04/multi-machine-support/ : _With this recent update, you can create identical machines that you can deploy to any provider you would like_) you could however easily duplicate the config.yaml and make one per machine so you can provision different software.

Comment: And how would you go about pointing one Vagrantfile at multiple config.yaml's?

Answer (score 6):

This isn't natively supported via the PuPHPet GUI, but... you can easily implement it.

Note: I will *not* offer support for the following via PuPHPet's github tracker. Please don't post tickets for this. However, I am using something similar to some freelance clients and it is working well.

PuPHPet has support for multiple config files, each extending and overriding the previous.

Take a look at `puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml`:

```
---
:backends: yaml
:yaml:
    :datadir: '/'
:hierarchy:
    - vagrant/puphpet/config-custom
    - vagrant/puphpet/config-%{::provisioner_type}
    - vagrant/puphpet/config
:merge_behavior: deeper
:logger: console
```

Hiera loads config files backwards, so it goes `config.yaml` -> `config-%{::provisioner_type}.yaml` -> `config-custom.yaml`.

You can insert a new line below `config-custom`: `- vagrant/puphpet/config-%{::server_type}`

This will inject any custom settings within this file into the Puppet environment. However, you still need to make Vagrant aware of it because Vagrant reads from `Vagrantfile` to execute commands. You might also need to do some custom work for each different server type. Note that `server_type` in this context can mean something like proxy, app, db, jenkins, etc.

Within the PuPHPet root directory, where `Vagrantfile` and `puphpet` directory exist, create new directories named after your server types.

For example, create a new `db` directory, delete your `Vagrantfile` and create a new one within this new directory, and create a `config-db.yaml` inside the `puphpet` directory:

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── db
│   └── Vagrantfile
└── puphpet
    ├── config-custom.yaml
    ├── config-custom.yaml.dist
    ├── config-db.yaml
    ├── config.yaml
    ├── files
    ├── puppet
    ├── ruby
    ├── shell
    └── vagrant
```

Your `db/Vagrantfile` contents can look like the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
dir = "#{dir}/.."

server_type = 'proxy'

VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH = "#{dir}/.vagrant";
currpath = ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'];
if(currpath.nil?)
    currpath = '.vagrant';
end
if(currpath != VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH)
    ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'] = VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH
    args = ARGV.join(' ');
    system "vagrant #{args}"

    if Dir.exists?('Directory Name')
        FileUtils.rm_r(currpath)
    end

    abort "Finished"
end

require 'yaml'
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/deep_merge.rb"
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/to_bool.rb"
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/puppet.rb"

configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")

provider = ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] ? ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] : 'local'
if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{server_type}.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{server_type}.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

data = configValues['vagrantfile']

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.1'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  eval File.read("#{dir}/puphpet/vagrant/Vagrantfile-#{data['target']}")
end
```

We've now told Vagrant about the new config file at `#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{server_type}.yaml` -> `#{dir}/puphpet/config-db.yaml` -> ..

Create as many of these for as many server types as you require.

If you want Puppet to be aware of the `server_type` value you can pass it in as a facter. Update the `vagrant/Vagrantfile-*` files with:

```
puppet.facter = {
    'server_name'      => "#{machine['id']}",
    'server_type'      => "#{server_type}",
    'fqdn'             => "#{machine_id.vm.hostname}",
    'ssh_username'     => "#{ssh_username}",
    'provisioner_type' => 'local',
}
```

and it will be available within your Puppet manifests as `$::server_type`.

So what's actually going on here?

Well, in your `config.yaml` (ie the master config file) you can setup the very basics of your server farm. Each server might require packages like `git` or have specific ports opened by the firewall. You can add those values there.

Set server-specific applications to not install in your `config.yaml`:

```
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 2.6.0
    databases: {  }
```

In your `config-db.yaml` you can set the DB-specific values as you wish:

```
mongodb:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        ensure: true
        package_name: mongodb-org-server
        bind_ip: "%{::ipaddress_tun0}"
        port: '27017'
        config: /etc/mongod.conf
        replset: rsmain
    globals:
        bind_ip: "%{::ipaddress_tun0}"
        version: 3.2.6
        service_name: mongodb
    databases:
         your_db:
             name: db_name
             user: db_user
             password: 'awesome_password'
```

Now your database server will pick up these changes and apply as needed. Your app server (or jenkins/proxy/etc) will still see `mongodb` as not needing installed from `config.yaml`. You can create fairly complex farms this way, all through a few simpel YAML files.

The last thing to note is that since this is a multi-server environment, Vagrant needs to know what server to work on when you run most commands. You do this by using the machine ID, which you will want to set in each `config-#{server_type}.yaml` file. Each file can have multiple machines defined for its type. Then simply append the machine ID to vagrant commands:

`vagrant up db1`, `vagrant destroy -f db1`, etc.

I hope this answers all your questions, or at least helps you get most of the way to what you are trying to accomplish!